# t-test difference in size of each sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have a daily process that's been going on for a few months. Now I'm trying to infer if a change to the process is significantly different. I let the new process run for two weeks because I can't afford to run it too much longer without knowing if it's a better process.

#### Questions

1. When computing the mean statistic for the original process, how many observations should I use? Does it have to be 14 to match the new process I'm evaluating?
2. If so, how could I choose what those 14 observations should be? Maybe just the most recent 14?
3. Could I use the 14 observations I have for the new process and measure it against a random sample of 14 observations from the original process? What would happen if I did this multiple times?

#### Edit - Adding clarity

To make my use case slightly more concrete, the "process" is the amount of clicks a digital ad campaign gets in a day. The original process is the ad campaign with all default settings. The new process is some change to how the campaign is optimized to hopefully produce more clicks.

Comment: If you know the variance $σ^2$ of the new process (or can make a good estimate) and you can specify how much change $δ$ in the mean you want to detect, and whether it's a one or two sided test, then you can find the power of detecting such a difference for $n=14$ observations. (By simulation, or analytically using the noncentral t distribution.) // You can search this site for something like `t test power and sample size`. Or see the simulation in my brief Answer.

Comment: For your questions 1,2,3: If $n=14$ gives you the power you want, then you can use 14 observations from the new process. I think you should do a 1 sample t test matching the new process against the established average of the relevant original process. (I'm assuming you must have a hundred or so observations from the original process--enough to be pretty sure what its average is.) Then there would be no point in doing repeated tests with samples from the original process. [If you ever need to compare two relatively new processes with about 14 obs. each, then use a Welch two-sample t test.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment** continued: Suppose you are doing a 2-sided, one-sample t test at the 5% level, with a random sample (independent observations) of size $n=14$ from a normal population. Also, suppose $\sigma=\delta$ in the notation of my Comment above, then you will have power (probability of detection/rejection) about 93%.

The first illustration (in R) is for testing $H_0: \mu=0$ vs $H_a: \mu \ne 0.$ The specific power is against an alternative $\delta =2$ away from $0$ and with $\sigma = 2.$ But for any $\sigma=\delta,$ the power will be the same, about 93%.

```
set.seed(1213)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(14, 2, 2))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.93312
```

Now for $\delta = \sigma = 3.$

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(14, 5, 3), mu=2)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.93303
```

Exact computation from a recent release of Minitab software.

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus ≠ null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 2

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         2      14  0.932369
```

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this machinery assumes that successive values are independent. For a "process" (whatever that means) running in time, that seems implausible, or at least an extreme case.

Comment: @NickCox. Thanks for comment. Serial correlation is certainly possible, Apparently, observations of the process are daily. I was assuming that's far enough apart for independence. Also assumed normality because OP seems somewhat familiar with t tests. Making edits so that these assumptions are on record. // Also, returning here after 'sleeping on it' to suggest that some sort of continual 'control chart' approach may  be better than testing after two weeks.

Comment: To make my use case slightly more concrete, the "process" is the amount of clicks a digital ad campaign gets in a day. The original process is the ad campaign with all default settings. The new process is some change to how the campaign is optimized to hopefully produce more clicks. (I added this clarity to the original post so others can find it easily).